# What is there a difference between Vanaspati and Vṛkṣa?

Tags: scripture, atma, manu-smriti, plants

The Manusmṛti seems to indicate that Vṛkṣa are angiosperms and Vanaspati are all other plants. Is there any further explanation of differences between the two, especially with regards to their spiritual nature?

(Actually, you could argue that it is actually describing the relationship just like modern taxonomy and Vanaspati are all plants and Vṛkṣa are angiosperms.)

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145462.html